# In which order Test NG tests will execute?

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

I have 2 TestNG class containing different tests.

For Eg:

```
 Class Test1{
      @Test
      public void Amazon(){

      }
 }

 Class Test2{
      @Test
      public void Netflix(){

      }
 }
```

In the above example Class Test1 & Test2 are two separate files. Now if you execute the project as "Run as TestNG Test" which one will execute first and why?

Thanks.

Comment: Which IDE do you use?

Comment: I am using Eclipse Neon IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order is not specified by TestNG and may change between TestNG, its plugin or even java version.

But you can imagine it takes classes in the alphabetic order:

- Test1#Amazon
- Test2#NetFlix

If you want a strong order between tests, you have to use one or more order features from TestNG like `dependsOnMethods`, `priority`, ...
Check [the documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods).